# IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() When I tried to provide activity in Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Main Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

}
```

Hilt Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideActivity(): MainActivity = MainActivity()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideActivityUtils(@ActivityRetainedScoped context: MainActivity): ActivityUtils = 
ActivityUtilsImpl(context)
}
```

And utils class with needed functions

```
class ActivityUtilsImpl @Inject constructor(@ActivityRetainedScoped private val activity: 
MainActivity) : ActivityUtils {

override fun showKeyboard() {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
InputMethodManager?
    imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0)
 }
}
```

When I try to call something from the utils class using an activity instance, I get the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate ()

Tried @ActivityContext the same thing, how can I make it call normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    @Singleton
>    @Provides
>    fun provideActivity(): MainActivity = MainActivity()
> ```

Never ever ever ever ever ever instantiate an Activity manually.

Should be

```
 @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
 @Module
 class ActivityModule {
     @Provides @ActivityScope fun activityUtils(activity: Activity): ActivityUtils = ActivityUtilsImpl(activity)
```

Comment: Yeah, it words thanks. I tried like this, but in one module, and have an error "different scopes". And why instantiate of Activity manually is bad?

Comment: Mostly because it won't work. The system creates them.